# Wordpress: using query_posts with custom sort

Tags: wordpress

I'm using

```
  <?php query_posts('cat=34546&posts_per_page=5&order=DESC');
```

in order to get five posts from a certain category. The order is determined by the ID of the post. I would like it to be determined by another field, like `post_date` column in posts (let's say for the sake of this question that I manually change `post_date` that in the database). How can this be done?

Comment: Don't ever use `query_posts()` for custom queries, use `get_posts()` or [WP_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Query Posts orderby parameters.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

For example:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=34546&posts_per_page=5&order=DESC&orderby=date');
```

The reference I linked above has what values you can use for orderby.